# Design for regression analysis

Tags: regression

I have a dataset of students, the number of times they were tutored in class, the number of times they were tutored after school, and their marks in terms 1 and 2.

```
      studid    DaysTutoredAfterSchool    DaysTutoredInClass    Term1    Term2
--  --------  ------------------------  --------------------  -------  -------
 1   2222180                         0                     1       37       23
 2   2227130                         3                     0       75       82
 4   2218584                         0                     0       30        3
10   2246718                         0                     4       57       72
11   2219509                         0                     1       55       50
```

Here's the full [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UnlHWNIaE3f3RyD7YOH3RC-8FWnARkGa/view?usp=sharing)

I'm trying to answer two questions:

1. Is there any association between the number of times a student was tutored and the difference in marks between terms 1 and 2?
2. Does being tutored in class vs after school make any difference in this association?

I've described my approaches below and bolded specific questions.  Any suggestions for how to approach this would be appreciated.

### Dividing the students into two groups

When I did this analysis last time (on a different dataset), I divided the students in two groups, those who were tutored 3 or more times (DaysTutoredAfterSchool + DaysTutoredInClass >=3) and those who were not.  The cutoff of 3 was arbitrary.  At the suggestion of [this answer on stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378003/how-do-i-evaluate-the-increase-decrease-in-a-set-of-test-scores-between-two-grou) I then ran a mixed linear regression model to compare the two groups.  Using the same method on this year's data yields this result

The dataset with the IsTutored column (DaysTutored = DaysTutoredAfterSchool + DaysTutoredInClass):

```
      studid    DaysTutored    Term1    Term2    IsTutored
--  --------  -------------  -------  -------  -----------
 1   2222180              1       37       23            0
 2   2227130              3       75       82            1
 4   2218584              0       30        3            0
10   2246718              4       57       72            1
11   2219509              1       55       50            0
```

The dataset reshaped for the regression model:

```
      studid    IsTutored  Term      Mark    IsTerm2
--  --------  -----------  ------  ------  ---------
 0   2222180            0  Term1       37          0
 1   2227130            1  Term1       75          0
 2   2218584            0  Term1       30          0
 3   2246718            1  Term1       57          0
 4   2219509            0  Term1       55          0
46   2222180            0  Term2       23          1
47   2227130            1  Term2       82          1
48   2218584            0  Term2        3          1
49   2246718            1  Term2       72          1
50   2219509            0  Term2       50          1
```

The formula
`sm.MixedLM.from_formula("Mark ~ IsTerm2*IsTutored",data,groups=data["studid"])`

The results

```
            Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
==============================================================
Model:               MixedLM   Dependent Variable:   Mark     
No. Observations:    92        Method:               REML     
No. Groups:          46        Scale:                51.8002  
Min. group size:     2         Likelihood:           -361.3434
Max. group size:     2         Converged:            Yes      
Mean group size:     2.0                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------
                   Coef.  Std.Err.   z    P>|z|  [0.025 0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept          65.633    3.490 18.804 0.000  58.792 72.475
IsTerm2            -9.533    1.858 -5.130 0.000 -13.176 -5.891
IsTutored          -0.571    5.918 -0.096 0.923 -12.171 11.029
IsTerm2:IsTutored  11.596    3.151  3.680 0.000   5.420 17.772
Group Var         313.703   14.227                            
==============================================================
```

I read the results as:

- Marks for students who were not tutored declined on average by -9.533 points from term 1 to term 2
- Marks for students who were tutored rose on average by 1.492

  - Term1 =  (65.633 - 0.571)
  - Term2 = (65.633 -9.533 + 11.596)
- Low P value of IsTerm2:IsTutored means the difference between the groups is statistically significant

### Using the DaysTutored continuous variable instead of dividing into groups

For this analysis, I'd like to incorporate the number of times students were tutored instead of simply dividing the students into groups.  I tried feeding the DaysTutored  column into the model.  Here's the dataset

```
      studid    DaysTutored  Term      Mark    IsTerm2
--  --------  -------------  ------  ------  ---------
 0   2222180              1  Term1       37          0
 1   2227130              3  Term1       75          0
 2   2218584              0  Term1       30          0
 3   2246718              4  Term1       57          0
 4   2219509              1  Term1       55          0
46   2222180              1  Term2       23          1
47   2227130              3  Term2       82          1
48   2218584              0  Term2        3          1
49   2246718              4  Term2       72          1
50   2219509              1  Term2       50          1
```

The formula:

`model2 = sm.MixedLM.from_formula("Mark ~ IsTerm2*DaysTutored",data2,groups=data2["studid"])`

The results:

```
             Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
================================================================
Model:               MixedLM    Dependent Variable:    Mark     
No. Observations:    92         Method:                REML     
No. Groups:          46         Scale:                 58.4521  
Min. group size:     2          Likelihood:            -370.5287
Max. group size:     2          Converged:             Yes      
Mean group size:     2.0                                        
----------------------------------------------------------------
                     Coef.  Std.Err.   z    P>|z|  [0.025 0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept            66.275    3.111 21.304 0.000  60.177 72.372
IsTerm2              -7.320    1.736 -4.216 0.000 -10.723 -3.917
DaysTutored          -0.192    0.282 -0.681 0.496  -0.745  0.361
IsTerm2:DaysTutored   0.416    0.157  2.645 0.008   0.108  0.725
Group Var           316.830   13.647                            
================================================================
```

I read these results as:

- Marks for students who were not tutored declined, on average, by -7.320 from term 1 to term 2
- Marks for students who were tutored rose, on average, by 0.416 points for every session (DaysTutored) they were tutored.  **Is this a correct interpretation?**

### DaysTutoredAfterSchool vs DaysTutoredInClass

I want to see if there is a difference between being tutored after school and being tutored in class.  I ran the same regression model with these two different tutoring variables:

The dataset:

```
      studid    DaysTutoredInClass    DaysTutoredAfterSchool  Term      Mark    IsTerm2
--  --------  --------------------  ------------------------  ------  ------  ---------
 0   2222180                     1                         0  Term1       37          0
 1   2227130                     0                         3  Term1       75          0
 2   2218584                     0                         0  Term1       30          0
 3   2246718                     4                         0  Term1       57          0
 4   2219509                     1                         0  Term1       55          0
46   2222180                     1                         0  Term2       23          1
47   2227130                     0                         3  Term2       82          1
48   2218584                     0                         0  Term2        3          1
49   2246718                     4                         0  Term2       72          1
50   2219509                     1                         0  Term2       50          1
```

The formula:

sm.MixedLM.from_formula("Mark ~ IsTerm2*DaysTutored",data2,groups=data2["studid"]

The results:

```
                            Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
==============================================================================================
Model:                         MixedLM              Dependent Variable:              Mark     
No. Observations:              92                   Method:                          REML     
No. Groups:                    46                   Scale:                           58.1336  
Min. group size:               2                    Likelihood:                      -365.2296
Max. group size:               2                    Converged:                       Yes      
Mean group size:               2.0                                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                   Coef.  Std.Err.   z    P>|z|  [0.025 0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                                          64.928    3.469 18.717 0.000  58.129 71.727
IsTerm2                                            -8.644    1.953 -4.425 0.000 -12.472 -4.816
DaysTutoredInClass                                 -0.167    0.862 -0.194 0.846  -1.857  1.522
IsTerm2:DaysTutoredInClass                          0.863    0.486  1.778 0.075  -0.089  1.815
DaysTutoredAfterSchool                              3.219    2.682  1.200 0.230  -2.037  8.475
IsTerm2:DaysTutoredAfterSchool                      2.491    1.510  1.650 0.099  -0.469  5.450
DaysTutoredInClass:DaysTutoredAfterSchool          -0.097    0.450 -0.215 0.830  -0.980  0.786
IsTerm2:DaysTutoredInClass:DaysTutoredAfterSchool  -0.287    0.254 -1.130 0.258  -0.784  0.211
Group Var                                         308.579   13.666                            
==============================================================================================
```

I think this means:

- Marks for students tutored in class rose, on average, 0.863 points for every day they were tutored after school.
- Marks for students tutored after school rose, on average, 2.491 points for every day they were tutored after school.

**Is this interpretation correct?  The P values for these coefs are not low enough.**

**What does the coef for IsTerm2:DaysTutoredInClass:DaysTutoredAfterSchool mean?**

Comment: Michael, can you clarify if you agregated the number of days tutored in class or after school across the two terms? Do you have access to this information for each term?

Comment: The tutoring began towards the end of the first term and ended at the end of the second term. So most of it occurred during the second term, which is why we are using the difference in the term marks as a measure. I don’t have data on the specific time periods for the tutoring.

Comment: There's a lot going on here that would make it challenging to ascribe (average) improvement in marks from term 1 to term 2 to tutoring: the tests in term 2 could have been easier than those in term 1, students who did poorly in term 1 may have spent additional time in the library to improve their grades, etc.